# Calling javaFX method from main method in regular java

Tags: java, methods, call, javafx-2

I have two projects:

1. A JavaFX GUI (2.0) class with this method called `showNewMessage(String msg)`
2. A "regular Java" class with a DB and stuff.

What I would like to do is to update the JavaFX GUI with this method `showNewMessage(String msg)`.  But the call should come from the java project every 5 seconds.

So it would go like this:

- Java project creates a list of messages
- Java project calls the `showNewMessage(String msg)`
- The JavaFX class updates it's scene
- The Java project waits 5 seconds before calling the `showNewMessage` again

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Should these projects run as 2 applications (2 JVMs) or in one application (1 JVM)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at interprocess communication between the applications.
It can be achieved numerous ways. RMI, sockets... etc

http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-03/03-qa-0324-ipc.html

E.g. The javafx application creates a server socket and reads data from the client. You can then call (shownewmessage) method passing the received data.